# jquery: некорретно работает функция, следящая за высотой блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, height

Есть функция, которая выравнивает по высоте блоки с различным содержимым:

```
    var myHeight = function() {
        var mh = 0;
        $(".block").each(function () {
            var h_block = parseInt($(this).height());
            if(h_block > mh) {
                mh = h_block;
            };
        });
        $(".block").height(mh);
    }
```

Вызываю её на загрузку страницы и на изменение размера экрана.

На $(window).load всё отрабатывает корректно.

А вот с $(window).resize есть проблемы: высота блоков не подстраивается под объем контента, в результате при уменьшении экрана содержимое начинает выползать снизу за пределы некоторых блоков.

Почему так происходит? Как это исправить?

Comment: А почему высота блоков должна подстраиваться под объем контента? В вашей функции нет такого.

Comment: @MaximZasorin, по умолчанию. Если блоку не задана высота, она подстраивается под содержимое автоматически

Comment: Но в вашем случае высота задается с помощью функции.

Comment: @MaximZasorin, да, но она получается путём сравнения высот всех блоков, которые, в свою очередь, формируются именно содержимым - иначе откуда функция узнает высоты блоков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое объяснение. При загрузке страницы у всех блоков значение `height` равно `auto`, и высота блоков вычисляется на основе контента, а метод `.height()` возвращает эту автоматически вычисленную высоту. После того, как ваша функция отработает, у всех блоков будет установлена фиксированная высота, и далее по событию `resize` метод `.height()` будет возвращать уже именно ее, и ваша функция никак не будет влиять на блоки.

Можно попробовать сбрасывать фиксированную высоту блоков перед очередным поиском максимальной высоты, через:

```
$(".block").height('auto');
```

В вашем случае вот так:

```
var myHeight = function() {
    var mh = 0;
    $(".block").height('auto');
    $(".block").each(function () {
        var h_block = parseInt($(this).height());
        if(h_block > mh) {
            mh = h_block;
        };
    });
    $(".block").height(mh);
}
```

Comment: я понял, да, спасибо большое!